# Jquery ajax() messing with my .htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, jquery, mod-rewrite

I am performing a simple AJAX() request using Jquery (Google hosted 1.7.1 jquery.min.js code)

The code is pretty simple:

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../inc/ajax_msgread_sendPM.php",
            data: "fromuserid=<?php echo $fromuserid; ?>&pmSubject=<?php echo urlencode($pmSubject); ?>&pmBody=" + pmReply,
            success: function(data){
            $("#showSuccess").show("fast");             
            $("#resultResponse").html(data);
            }
        });
```

The mod_rewrite .htaccess for this document is:

```
RewriteRule ^messages/read/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /msgread.php?usernam=$1&keynode=$2 [QSA,L]
```

When I view the $resultResponse for some reason the Ajax keeps wanting to turn $1 into 'inc' so any unrelated (or related) mySQL queries using `$_GET["usernam"]` from the URL ends up returning 'inc'

Why is this happening?  There is no relation between my script and the mod_rewrite.  There are no variables named "usernam" or "1" on the script (or anywhere on the site).

Firebug gives no help.

Advice please?

UPDATE:

I see where the problem is coming from.. in the ajax jquery code:

url: "../inc/ajax_msgread_sendPM.php",

the "inc" keeps getting set as the username because of its location based on the mod_rewrite rules... I need to somehow exclude this from mod_rewrite... just not sure how to solve this problem

Comment: What is full **real** url your browser performs the request to? (see it by firebug)

Comment: sure.. it is:www.domain.com/inc/ajax_msgread_sendPM.php for the serverside script

Comment: and it is www.domain.com/messages/read/username/NQ.. for the scripr

Comment: Are you sure it is `www.domain.com/inc/ajax_msgread_sendPM.php`? How did you get this url?

Comment: "I need to somehow exclude this from mod_rewrite." --- you don't need, you just need to specify **correct** url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as current url for your page is

```
www.domain.com/messages/read/username/NQ
```

and you use **relative** path - it is being rewritten to

```
www.domain.com/messages/read/username/inc/ajax_msgread_sendPM.php
```

which is definitely not what you want. The simplest solution would be to change the ajax endpoint url to:

```
url: "/inc/ajax_msgread_sendPM.php",
```