# SEO friendly url creation using js, php in html page

Tags: php, jquery, html, seo

I am developing a website for a client using html, js and php. For any database call i am using ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "index2.php",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg, status) {
      dosomething(msg);
     },
     error: function (msg, status) {
          console.log("failure");
          console.log(msg);
     }
 });
```

and php pages returns me the output. The problem is that index.html page url is not getting changed.....I want it to change say index.html?id=23  (creating query string in html page)

Basically my aim to make it SEO friendly url like index.html/helloppl
What is the best method to do this. While googling i found [link](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/friendurl/)  for doing....still i need to create query string here...any help is appreciated.

1. Creating SEO fridenly url.
2. Creating query string in html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `index.html` page url is not getting changed.  I want it to change say `index.html?id=23` (creating query string in html page)

Ans: if you want to change the url like you have mention above this the ajax will not the way to do this . This can be done in simple way go to the url i have provided and look at the topic.

http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php

Basically my aim to make it SEO friendly url like `index.html/helloppl`.  What is the best method to do this. While googling i found link for doing this.  I still need to create query string here.

Ans: This can be done with htaccess.  Go To The Link

[Jquery ajax() messing with my .htaccess mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319147/jquery-ajax-messing-with-my-htaccess-mod-rewrite)